# ReacJS CSSTransitionGroup how can i make my transition smoother and remove transition from element

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, reactcsstransitiongroup

Hello im trying to to keep my button `position:absolute` but remove the animation from it also my animation is not smooth enough and i can't really handle it cause no key frames. here is my bin.

[My Bin](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KmWYIwPrjZiZPwmAAwg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `top` of `.changeImage`. I added `top: 60px` and it stayed in place when toggling images. Is that what you were trying to achieve?